# React App falls back to root index, unless resetting cache

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app

In Chrome, if I request an URL of e.g. `https://example.com/privacy`, where an ejected `create-react-app` lies at the root web path, the response is the contents of `http://example.com/index.html`! This is an issue, as a static `privacy` folder with an `index.html` exists in the web root path, and if requested should obviously not return the root web page. My suspicion is that this is the work of one or more service workers. I'm not too familiar with how they work, but the only thing currently on my mind is getting the `https://example.com/privacy` scenario to work, i.e. return `https://example.com/privacy/index.html` and not `https://example.com/index.html`.

I've tried renaming the `service-worker.js` to `service-worker__.js` as it feels like it's causing more trouble than good right now, but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Is this in development or production? If in development, the Webpack dev server will use [historyApiFallback](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback) to serve `index.html` for every request taht gives 404.

Comment: @Tholle The React app was built running `npm run build` with production configuration, and the built files was put on the server

Comment: Alright. It might be worth looking into [unregistering the service worker](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#opting-out-of-caching) if you know it's not the server that serves `index.html` for all 404 requests. You just write `import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker'; unregister();` in your `src/index.js` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ruled out that your server is not serving `index.html` for every 404 request, it's most likely the service worker that is at fault.

You can import the `unregister` function and call that to unregister the service worker.

**src/index.js**

```
import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';

unregister();
```

Comment: Just adding that it seems odd that requesting the `privacy` example would return a 404 response when the `privacy` file clearly exists. Maybe that's related to client cache?

Comment: @JohanSvensson Yes, I think you are right. It's most likely a cached response.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tholle pointed out, the solution was to call `unregister()` in `index.js` to unregister the service worker.